# How can I use dispatch group to start loading at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

For faster loading, I would like to use dispatch group, but how to do that in this case?

At the same time I want to start loading workoutRepository and streakRepository.

```
private func loadDailyWorkout(completion: @escaping ((DailyWorkout) -> Void)) {
    workoutRepository.load { [weak self] (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let list):
            if list.isEmpty {
                self?.shouldShowWorkoutUnlockedScreen = true
            }
            self?.streakRepository.load { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let streak):
                    let workout = DailyWorkout(streak: streak, tricks: list)
                    completion(workout)
                case .failure:
                    let workout = DailyWorkout(streak: Streak.initial, tricks: list)
                    completion(workout)
                }
            }
        default:
            completion(DailyWorkout(streak: Streak.initial, tricks: []))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in your code you only load `streakRepository` if `workoutRepository` was _successful_. As long as you place that restriction on things, you _cannot_ do them simultaneously.

Comment: But if you are willing to do them both regardless of whether one of them succeeds, then just use a DispatchGroup, exactly as you say.

Comment: @matt could you please give me an example how should it be? As these Dispatch Groups are bit headache for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch:

```
private func loadDailyWorkout(completion: @escaping ((DailyWorkout) -> Void)) {
    myBackgroundQueue.async {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var streak = // Optional of the right type, initially nil
        var list = // Optional of the right type, initially nil
        group.enter()
        workoutRepository.load { result in {
            // do stuff; set list
            group.leave()
        }
        group.enter()
        streakRepository.load { result in
            // do stuff; set streak
            group.leave()
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) { 
            // can see streak and list
            // so now go ahead and do your callback
        }
    }
}
```

Both `load` commands are executed simultaneously, but we do not proceed afterwards (`notify`) until both have completed.

Note that I start by putting us on a background queue, because we must not "wait" on the main queue. This might not be necessary in your case.

Comment: thx! Just still have doubt. both should return DailyWorkout. and both needs both parameters: streak, and tricks. So one method loads streaks, another loads tricks. How to use in group.notify so I get both streaks and tricks in one place then? That is the biggest issue for me at the moment :)

Comment: Locally (at the same level as `let group`) declare Optional variables, and set them in the `load` completion handlers. Thus, by the time you get to the `group.notify` completion handler, those Optionals are either still `nil` or they have been set by the `load` completion handlers, and that is where you do whatever it is you want to do (calling the overall completion with a workout).

Comment: I would also like to say that if you are on iOS 13 and later, the Combine framework gives you a much clearer way to express this sort of thing.

Comment: Modified my sketch to show how to communicate the `load` results down to the `group.notify`.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thank you a lot! Actually, I was thinking of that, but thought there is a more clean way to do so! Thanks once again for the time and help ;)

Comment: Yeah, if you can use the Combine framework, that gives you a cleaner way (in my opinion). That's because you can `zip` the two publishers (Futures wrapped around the `load` commands) and the resulting values, the list and streak, just fall into your lap as a single tuple. With DispatchQueue `async` and DispatchGroup, it almost feels like you are jumping backwards and forward in time, because that's what you are doing; with Combine, everything just flows forwards down the pipeline.

Comment: The asynchronous dispatch to the `myBackgroundQueue` is superfluous and should be removed..

Comment: @Rob agreed, I said in my answer that it might not be needed (last paragraph)

Comment: It just seems strange to say “hey, here’s how you have these two asynchronous methods run concurrently and then also dispatch the whole thing to a background queue”. Either they’re asynchronous and the dispatch queue is redundant or they’re not and then you’re not achieving concurrent requests and the dispatch group is redundant. (Sorry to belabor the obvious; I know you get this!)